# How to get all the files which is modified or added yesterday from SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query

I am trying to get all the files which is modified or added yesterday from SharePoint document library using below code.

```
List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
clientContext.Load(list);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='Recursive'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name = 'Modified'/><Value Type = 'DateTime'> <Today OffsetDays='-1'/></Value ></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
ListItemCollection listCol = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(listCol);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
int cnt = listCol.Count;
foreach (var item in listCol)
{
          TestingFiles(clientContext, item.FieldValues["FileDirRef"].ToString());
}
```

Please note that the value of OffsetDays is -1.

But with the above code I am getting all the files instead only yesterdays files. Any idea what went wrong in my code.        Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the Caml query commands. It works great. I can get all yesterday files (Modified = yesterday).

What is the "`TestingFiles`" function used for in your code?

Output all filenames from item collection to see if you get correct item results.

```
List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName); 
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml =
    @"<View Scope='Recursive'>
    <Query>
        <Where>
        <Eq><FieldRef Name ='Modified'/><Value Type ='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='-1'/></Value></Eq>
        </Where>
    </Query>
    </View>";
ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(listItems);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (ListItem oListItem in listItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(oListItem["FileRef"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(oListItem.FieldValues["FileDirRef"].ToString());
}
```

**Update:**
entire code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Security;

namespace TestGetFiles
{
    class Program
    {


        private class Configuration
        {
            public static string ServiceSiteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/<site>";
            public static string ServiceUserName = "admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
            public static string ServicePassword = "<password>";
        }

        static ClientContext GetonlineContext()
        {
            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in Configuration.ServicePassword)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }
            var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Configuration.ServiceUserName, securePassword);
            var context = new ClientContext(Configuration.ServiceSiteUrl);
            context.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
            return context;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
            var clientContext=GetonlineContext();  
            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("<library>"); 
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml =
                @"<View Scope='Recursive'>
                <Query>
                    <Where>
                    <Eq><FieldRef Name ='DateTest'/><Value Type ='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='-1'/></Value></Eq>
                    </Where>
                </Query>
                </View>";
            ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.Load(listItems);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (ListItem oListItem in listItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(oListItem["FileRef"].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(oListItem.FieldValues["FileDirRef"].ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadLine();      

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I used the same code as yours but still the query is fetching all the files.

Comment: Could you please provide the entire code you are running?

Comment: I updated my reply and added my entire code. Please test my code.

Comment: Please ensure you are using the latest SharePoint Online client SDK.

Comment: I did the same as your code with slight changes in CQML query. Replaced DateTest with Modified but getting all the files instead yesterdays file.

Comment: one more things to add here that my doc library has more than 1.2 lacs files. Will it be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please find my code as below.

```
private static void Testingfunction(ClientContext clientContext, string listName)
        {
            try
            {
                List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
                clientContext.Load(list);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml =
                    @"<View Scope='Recursive'>
                        <Query>
                            <Where>
                                <Eq><FieldRef Name ='Modified'/><Value Type ='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='-1'/></Value></Eq>
                            </Where>
                        </Query>
                      </View>";
                ListItemCollection listCol = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
                clientContext.Load(listCol);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (ListItem oListItem in listCol)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File Name: " + oListItem["FileRef"].ToString());
                    strLog.AppendLine("File Name: " + oListItem["FileRef"].ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("File url: " + oListItem.FieldValues["FileDirRef"].ToString());
                    strLog.AppendLine("File url: " + oListItem.FieldValues["FileDirRef"].ToString());
                    filecount++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                strLog.AppendLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Err104 - Function name -> Testing function : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is no caml query string in camlQuery.ViewXml = @" "; in your code. You need to write query string.

Comment: I updated my reply and added my entire code. Please test my code.

Comment: In addition, are you using the latest SharePoint Online client SDK?